# sins of heart and their connection with faith

Tags: sin, imaan

selam alejkum. I have been reading about islam for 10 years but I suffer from a weird mental disorder that often makes me incapable of understanding things that are simpler than 1+1=2 due to my inability to feel and percept well the system of thoughts and feelings that come to my mind. So please answer my question straight to the point and don’t deviate the answer by explaining the pillars of islam, magic, quranic advice, stories from the sunna with hadiths etc… Please answer straight to the point: Is it kufr, major, minor or not sinful at all? Because the majority of the muslims that I sent question deviate their answer by explaining the pillars of islam, a story from Koran or hadith or black magic. So I repeat please answer straight to the point: Is it kufr , major, minor or not sinful at all? This is the question: There is something called process of thinking. People think about different things. They recall (bring to mind) something they have seen , heard or learned. Or imagine what it would look like if we were the size of an ant and wandered and walked inside the body of a tree. They recall a detail like an ugly scene of a car accident or the harsh voice of someone that has insulted somebody. They visualize the bloody face of somebody that comes out from a crashed car. In the vast majority of cases this happens with no intent of insulting someone. if someone were to bring to mind the following thought with no evil intent but he fantasizes it like a blockbuster fantasy movie or he paints something in his imagination like a Japanese manga or something surreal like ALICE IN WONDERLAND but I repeat he has absolutely no evil intent: What would it look like if god had a body identical to human beings and an arrow speared his body? Or people lived inside his body. Or a doctor operated his genital organ and intimate parts. Or somebody damaged his genital organ and anus with a spear. He imagines this without being emotional just like he imagines a tree without being emotional because he is sure within himself that god has nothing to do with that. Or he imagines this in an emotional manner because he fears sins of heart. I swear i am not a hypocryte or someone with bad intentions so please answer my question. isn't it discriminatory not to answer a question simply because god has given me a calamity? People with ocd are not held to account for kufr things that come from their illness. But it is a must for me to know things that are kufr. So please answer my question. He suffers from compulsive waswaas and speaks words of kufr; does he have to do anything? 200949 is question number in islamqa https://islamqa.info islamqa says that people with ocd are not held to account for kufr things that come as a result of their illness. So please answer my question whether what i described constitutes kufr or not? Because as a human being i have the right to know what is kufr and not kufr .
i expected muslims to be more good than the average.

الإسلام سؤال وجواب
موقع دعوي، علمي تربوي يهدف إلى تقديم الفتاوى والإجابات العلمية المؤصلة عن الأسئلة المتعلقة بالإسلام بشكل واف وميسر قدر الاستطاعة
islamqa.info

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general, these thoughts constitute Kufr because Allah (ﷻ) is Exalted and far Above these things you have described and they are untrue. Having these thoughts does not mean a person has gotten the sin of Kufr unless they do it **intentionally**. If they get these thoughts unintentionally such as a result of a mental disorder, then as IslamQA correctly pointed out, it is excused. This is your straightforward answer.

If you have any more questions or need me to expand, let me know!

Wa Alaikum As Salam!